Asset validation failed Invalid Signature. Code failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s)
I'm getting this error when trying to upload my application to the market. I think the error is not caused by a version error or image error because it does not pose any problem. I couldn't upload my first application to my market account. I wanted to push a basic application to test if it was an application-related problem, but it gave these errors too. I added my certificates to the account, but I don't understand why it gives this error. Can you help me?


Erorr full view

enter link description here
